# Social login, spring-security-oauth2 and spring-security-jwt?

Tags: spring-security, spring-boot, jwt, spring-security-oauth2

I'm developing a rest service which is going to be available in browser via
browser single page app and a mobile app. At the moment my service is working
without spring at all. The oauth2 client is implemented inside filters so to say "by hand".

I'm trying to migrate it to spring boot.
Much manuals read and much info googled and I'm trying to understand if the
following is actually possible for a customer:

1. Authorize with facebook oauth2 service (and get an access_token) with all the help
   from spring-security-oauth2.
2. Create a JWT and pass it to the client so that all further requests are
   backed with the JWT.

Since in my opinion spring boot is all about the configuration and declarations
I want to understand if this is possible with spring-security-oauth2 and
spring-security-jwt?

I'm not askng for a solution but just a yes/no from knowledge bearers since I'm deep in
the spring manuals and the answer becomes further...

Comment: Given this use-case is fairly common these days, I am surprised to see no answers yet (even after about 4 months). @Grigory, did you find anything yourself?

Answer (score 2):

short answer: Yes you can do it!

You have to add security dependencies to your build.gradle or pom.xml file:

```
compile "org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-security"
compile "org.springframework.security:spring-security-config"
compile "org.springframework.security:spring-security-data"
compile "org.springframework.security:spring-security-web"

compile "org.springframework.social:spring-social-security"
compile "org.springframework.social:spring-social-google"
compile "org.springframework.social:spring-social-facebook"
compile "org.springframework.social:spring-social-twitter"
```

then you have to add social config to your project alongside with your security config:

```
@Configuration
@EnableSocial
public class SocialConfiguration implements SocialConfigurer {

    private final Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(SocialConfiguration.class);

    private final SocialUserConnectionRepository socialUserConnectionRepository;

    private final Environment environment;

    public SocialConfiguration(SocialUserConnectionRepository socialUserConnectionRepository,
            Environment environment) {

        this.socialUserConnectionRepository = socialUserConnectionRepository;
        this.environment = environment;
    }

    @Bean
    public ConnectController connectController(ConnectionFactoryLocator connectionFactoryLocator,
            ConnectionRepository connectionRepository) {

        ConnectController controller = new ConnectController(connectionFactoryLocator, connectionRepository);
        controller.setApplicationUrl(environment.getProperty("spring.application.url"));
        return controller;
    }

    @Override
    public void addConnectionFactories(ConnectionFactoryConfigurer connectionFactoryConfigurer, Environment environment) {
        // Google configuration
        String googleClientId = environment.getProperty("spring.social.google.client-id");
        String googleClientSecret = environment.getProperty("spring.social.google.client-secret");
        if (googleClientId != null && googleClientSecret != null) {
            log.debug("Configuring GoogleConnectionFactory");
            connectionFactoryConfigurer.addConnectionFactory(
                new GoogleConnectionFactory(
                    googleClientId,
                    googleClientSecret
                )
            );
        } else {
            log.error("Cannot configure GoogleConnectionFactory id or secret null");
        }

        // Facebook configuration
        String facebookClientId = environment.getProperty("spring.social.facebook.client-id");
        String facebookClientSecret = environment.getProperty("spring.social.facebook.client-secret");
        if (facebookClientId != null && facebookClientSecret != null) {
            log.debug("Configuring FacebookConnectionFactory");
            connectionFactoryConfigurer.addConnectionFactory(
                new FacebookConnectionFactory(
                    facebookClientId,
                    facebookClientSecret
                )
            );
        } else {
            log.error("Cannot configure FacebookConnectionFactory id or secret null");
        }

        // Twitter configuration
        String twitterClientId = environment.getProperty("spring.social.twitter.client-id");
        String twitterClientSecret = environment.getProperty("spring.social.twitter.client-secret");
        if (twitterClientId != null && twitterClientSecret != null) {
            log.debug("Configuring TwitterConnectionFactory");
            connectionFactoryConfigurer.addConnectionFactory(
                new TwitterConnectionFactory(
                    twitterClientId,
                    twitterClientSecret
                )
            );
        } else {
            log.error("Cannot configure TwitterConnectionFactory id or secret null");
        }

        // jhipster-needle-add-social-connection-factory
    }

    @Override
    public UserIdSource getUserIdSource() {
        return new AuthenticationNameUserIdSource();
    }

    @Override
    public UsersConnectionRepository getUsersConnectionRepository(ConnectionFactoryLocator connectionFactoryLocator) {
        return new CustomSocialUsersConnectionRepository(socialUserConnectionRepository, connectionFactoryLocator);
    }

    @Bean
    public SignInAdapter signInAdapter(UserDetailsService userDetailsService, JHipsterProperties jHipsterProperties,
            TokenProvider tokenProvider) {
        return new CustomSignInAdapter(userDetailsService, jHipsterProperties,
            tokenProvider);
    }

    @Bean
    public ProviderSignInController providerSignInController(ConnectionFactoryLocator connectionFactoryLocator, UsersConnectionRepository usersConnectionRepository, SignInAdapter signInAdapter) {
        ProviderSignInController providerSignInController = new ProviderSignInController(connectionFactoryLocator, usersConnectionRepository, signInAdapter);
        providerSignInController.setSignUpUrl("/social/signup");
        providerSignInController.setApplicationUrl(environment.getProperty("spring.application.url"));
        return providerSignInController;
    }

    @Bean
    public ProviderSignInUtils getProviderSignInUtils(ConnectionFactoryLocator connectionFactoryLocator, UsersConnectionRepository usersConnectionRepository) {
        return new ProviderSignInUtils(connectionFactoryLocator, usersConnectionRepository);
    }
}
```

then you have to write adapter for your social login:

```
public class CustomSignInAdapter implements SignInAdapter {

    @SuppressWarnings("unused")
    private final Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(CustomSignInAdapter.class);

    private final UserDetailsService userDetailsService;

    private final JHipsterProperties jHipsterProperties;

    private final TokenProvider tokenProvider;


    public CustomSignInAdapter(UserDetailsService userDetailsService, JHipsterProperties jHipsterProperties,
            TokenProvider tokenProvider) {
        this.userDetailsService = userDetailsService;
        this.jHipsterProperties = jHipsterProperties;
        this.tokenProvider = tokenProvider;
    }

    @Override
    public String signIn(String userId, Connection<?> connection, NativeWebRequest request){
        try {
            UserDetails user = userDetailsService.loadUserByUsername(userId);
            UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken authenticationToken = new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(
                user,
                null,
                user.getAuthorities());

            SecurityContextHolder.getContext().setAuthentication(authenticationToken);
            String jwt = tokenProvider.createToken(authenticationToken, false);
            ServletWebRequest servletWebRequest = (ServletWebRequest) request;
            servletWebRequest.getResponse().addCookie(getSocialAuthenticationCookie(jwt));
        } catch (AuthenticationException ae) {
            log.error("Social authentication error");
            log.trace("Authentication exception trace: {}", ae);
        }
        return jHipsterProperties.getSocial().getRedirectAfterSignIn();
    }

    private Cookie getSocialAuthenticationCookie(String token) {
        Cookie socialAuthCookie = new Cookie("social-authentication", token);
        socialAuthCookie.setPath("/");
        socialAuthCookie.setMaxAge(10);
        return socialAuthCookie;
    }
}
```

you can find sample project in my github:
https://github.com/ksadjad/oauth-test

Comment: Hey @ksadjad , after following your guide, 
the following line
     ```   return jHipsterProperties.getSocial().getRedirectAfterSignIn();````
makes the cookie disappear due to 302 result code, do you know how to make the cookie stay on the browser?